# python firestore - db.collections arguments error

Tags: python, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using python with firestore client, and trying to run the tutorial example [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) with the following code:

```
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
cred = credentials.Certificate("cred.json")
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
db = firestore.client()
ref = db.collections("jobs")
```

> ref = db.collections("jobs") TypeError: collections() takes 1
>   positional argument but 2 were given

What am I missing here? the credentials file is legit, and the table is an existing table in my firestore.

and getting this error:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`collections` method](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/firestore/client.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1beta1.client.Client.collections) that you're calling returns all collections, and takes no arguments.

You're looking for the [`collection` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_multiple_documents_from_a_collection) (singular, without an `s`), which takes a single parameter (the name of the collection to return).